# Is it possible to craft items with > 100 energy without paying?

Tags: spiral-knights

In SK, some items (three-star and more) require 100+ energy (I have one now for 200 energy). I'm not looking to spend real-world dollars on this; is there a way to actually craft these items?

There's an option to buy in-game energy for crowns, but I'm not sure if that will allow me to breach the limit of 100, or if it will deteriorate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crystal Energy bought with crowns from other players (either via trade or via the in-game interface) is indistinguishable from Crystal Energy bought directly from Three Rings / Sega.

It's entirely possible to turn crowns into CE into items - the question, as with all Freemium games, is how much of your time you're willing to spend to do so.

Crystal Energy doesn't deteriorate, so buy as much as you need with crowns and don't fret!

Comment: Are you saying when I buy energy with crowns, and I'm at 100 already (full tank), it goes into some sort of credit?

Comment: @ashes999 Not quite. Directly below your Mist energy is another set of digits with the CE symbol (the cyan `-` sign). All purchased energy goes into *that* counter, which is both separate from your mist, and capable of going into 6+ digit values (i.e., more than you'd ever need).

Comment: Okay, I'm a bit confused. Lets define the two energies as "white number" (cyan bar) and "magenta number" (five-digit counter). When you purchase energy with crowns, does it increment the white or magenta number, and how does that impact crafting items that require more than 100 energy -- which is the limit of the white number?

Comment: @ashes999 stand by. I'll add pictures to my answer when I can.

Comment: @ashes999 in the mean time, purchasing energy with crowns (or cash) *or* trading energy with players will fill the magenta number. Crafting items with more than 100 energy will take from the white number first (Mist Energy / ME) and then whatever else is needed from Crystal Energy (CE).

Comment: Perfect, no pictures necessary. Cheers.